# Need help to optimize this query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Can you help me to optimize this query of mine? I've ran out of ways to optimize this. The data retrieval time here is 6 mins and I want to lessen it. Hope you can help me.

```
-- Main query
DECLARE @ProdClass VARCHAR(10)
,@ModelID VARCHAR(10)
,@ServiceStartDate DATETIME
,@ServiceEndDate DATETIME
,@SvcID VARCHAR(10)
,@StateID VARCHAR(10)
,@AreaID VARCHAR(10)

 SET @ProdClass = 'WPS'
 SET @ModelID = 'BM'
 SET @ServiceStartDate = convert(datetime, '10/1/2007')
 SET @ServiceEndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '11/1/2007')
 SET @SvcID = '358'
 SET @StateID = 'JB'
 SET @AreaID = ''

SELECT DISTINCT cus.MCUS_CUSID
    ,cus.MCUS_ENAME
    ,mod.MMOD_ENAME
    ,rou.MROU_SERNO
    ,svc.MSVC_SVCID AS SVC_NAME
    ,ar.MARE_ENAME
    ,dbo.ufn_GetLastXApptDate(rou.MROU_ROUID) AS MROU_APTDT
    ,rou.MROU_LSVDT
    ,(
        CASE MROU_FRSVE
        WHEN 'Y'
            THEN 'FREE'
        WHEN 'N'
            THEN 'NORMAL'
        END
    ) AS SERVICE_DUE_TYPE
FROM dbo.MROU_FIL AS rou
INNER JOIN dbo.MCUS_FIL AS cus ON rou.MROU_CUSID = cus.MCUS_CUSID
INNER JOIN dbo.MMOD_FIL AS mod ON rou.MROU_MODID = mod.MMOD_MODID
INNER JOIN dbo.MSVC_FIL AS svc ON rou.MROU_SVCID = svc.MSVC_SVCID
INNER JOIN dbo.MADR_FIL AS adr ON cus.MCUS_CUSID = adr.MADR_CUSID
INNER JOIN dbo.MSTA_FIL AS st ON adr.MADR_STAID = st.MSTA_STAID
INNER JOIN dbo.MARE_FIL AS ar ON adr.MADR_AREID = ar.MARE_AREID
INNER JOIN dbo.FAPT_FIL AS apt ON rou.MROU_ROUID = apt.FAPT_ROUID
WHERE rou.MROU_STAT = 'ACTIVE'
AND rou.MROU_CUSPF = 'MY'
AND apt.FAPT_APTTY in ('mf','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6', 'mm')
AND ((@ProdClass = '') OR (@ProdClass <> '' AND rou.MROU_CLSID = @ProdClass))
AND ((@ModelID = '') OR (@ModelID <> '' AND rou.MROU_MODID = @ModelID))
AND (
    ((@ServiceStartDate = '') OR (@ServiceStartDate <> '' AND rou.MROU_LSVDT >= @ServiceStartDate))
    AND
    ((@ServiceEndDate = '') OR (@ServiceEndDate <> '' AND rou.MROU_LSVDT <= @ServiceEndDate))
)
AND ((@SvcID = '') OR (@SvcID <> '' AND svc.MSVC_SVCID = @SvcID))
AND ((@StateID = '') OR (@StateID <> '' AND adr.MADR_STAID = @StateID))
AND ((@AreaID = '') OR (@AreaID <> '' AND adr.MADR_AREID = @AreaID))
ORDER BY rou.MROU_LSVDT


-- function -- 
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetLastXApptDate] 
(
@rouid numeric(18,0)
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ApptDate datetime

    SELECT @ApptDate = MAX(FAPT_APTDT)
    FROM dbo.FAPT_FIL
    WHERE FAPT_ROUID = @rouid
        AND FAPT_STAT= 'X'
        AND FAPT_APTTY in ('mf','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6', 'mm')

    RETURN @ApptDate

END
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?  If none, start there.

Comment: A lot actually. I don't know where to start.

Comment: There should be at least indexes on each of the keys on which you perform your joins - unless the tables are really small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server has to call the scalar function for every row.  To give it freedom to execute the function's query as a set based operation, move the function inline.  Change:

```
,dbo.ufn_GetLastXApptDate(rou.MROU_ROUID) AS MROU_APTDT
```

to:

```
,(
 SELECT  MAX(FAPT_APTDT)
 FROM    dbo.FAPT_FIL
 WHERE   FAPT_ROUID = rou.MROU_ROUID
         AND FAPT_STAT= 'X'
         AND FAPT_APTTY in ('mf','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6', 'mm')
 )
```

Your query also looks like a search query that might benefit from a different version of the execution plan for different values of parameters.  You can force a new query plan for each execution by adding:

```
option  (recompile)
```

at the end of the query.

Comment: If you want to maintain keeping this code in a function, convert it to a table function that returns: rouid, LastXApptDate. You won't get same performance boost as this answer, but you can still reuse the code.

Comment: @JeffO: An [inline table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx) would be just as efficient as inlining the code.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much! I didn't know that the calling of the function always affects the performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

try creating index with all the columns on your keys on which you perform your joins in the order they appear in your query for each table..